# Return JSON data from WebAPI Controller

Tags: asp.net, json, jqgrid, asp.net-web-api

I want to return some JSON data from my WebAPI controller and I want the returned data to be like this.

```
{"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","amila","amila","False"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","rakhitha","rakhitha","False"]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","Chathura","Chathura","False"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Geethaga","Geethaga","False"]}]}
```

But when I use the below code,

```
return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult()
        {
            Data = jsonData,
            JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
```

the data is returned like this.

```
{"Data":{"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1","amila","amila","False"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","rakhitha","rakhitha","False"]},{"id":3,"cell":["3","Chathura","Chathura","False"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Geethaga","Geethaga","False"]}]},"JsonRequestBehavior":0}
```

There is an additional JSON key as "Data". I dont want that parameter and as my implementation I cant remove this "Data" part after getting it to the client side. Because the data received from the server is directly used to fill a jqGrid. The code is below.

```
$("#Grid1").jqGrid({
            url: 'api/matchingservicewebapi/GetUser',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['', 'Name', 'FullName', 'IsActive'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 200 },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 300 },
                { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', width: 300 },
                { name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', width: 300 }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'Id',
            viewrecoreds: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            imgpath: 'Themes/images'
    }).navGrid(pager, { edit: true, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: true });
```

How do I remove this "Data" part? Because when you have this "Data" key in the returned JSON, jqGrid is not capable of filling that data to the grid.

I am using WebAPI Controller to return this data. But I tried using MVC3 controller, then this "Data" key was not in the returned JSON and data filled to the grid successfully. But I want to use WebAPI Controller. Please help to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set jsonreader option in jqGrid. like

```
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
...
   jsonReader : {root:"Data"},
...
});
```

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_string

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. But is there a way to define if I do not have a root element. I mean like, jsonReader : {root:""}

Answer (score 13):

JsonResult is an MVC concept. For Web API, your controller can simply return a CLR object and it will be serialized into JSON (assuming the client asks for JSON).

The result you're seeing is because the entire JsonResult object is getting serialized into JSON.

To get started with Web API, see: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

(Or you could continue to use an MVC controller ... is there a particular reason that you wanted to use a Web API controller?)

Answer (score 4):

Json.NET works well for me. Just return the JObject in the Web API

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm

```
JObject o = JObject.FromObject(new
{
  channel = new
 {
   title = "James Newton-King",
   link = "http://james.newtonking.com",
   description = "James Newton-King's blog.",
   item =
       from p in posts
       orderby p.Title
       select new
       {
         title = p.Title,
         description = p.Description,
         link = p.Link,
         category = p.Categories
    }
```

}
 })

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.d` instead of data in your code.

```
 success: function(data){
               //create jquery object from the response html
               var response=$(data.d);
               //Your binding logic here
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return the data in jqgrid required format. If you don't want to create a separate class for this, use dynamic return type in apicontroller. See working example [here](http://goo.gl/y4389).